# how can i know the id of an item in the listview when it has been filtered? Android

Tags: android, listview

can you help me guys, 
cause i made a edittext on top of the listview for filtering data on time, but when it has been filtered, the first index is always been 0... thus i filter the 50th line, i failed to get its parent id

```
public class Moshimoshi extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private ListView lv;
private EditText ed;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterForListview;
ContentResolver cr;
private long[] item_id;
private String lv_arr[];
int textlength = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    cr = getContentResolver();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    adapterForListview = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    viewData();
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lv_arr));
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                long id) {

            Log.i(String.valueOf(id), String.valueOf(item_id[(int)   id]));
            Intent info = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Info.class);
            int rowid = (int) item_id[(int) id];
            info.putExtra("key", rowid);

            // update.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            //
            startActivity(info);
        }
    });
    ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            textlength = ed.getText().length();
            adapterForListview.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < lv_arr.length; i++) {
                if (textlength <= lv_arr[i].length()) {
                    if (ed.getText()
                            .toString()
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                    (String) lv_arr[i].subSequence(0,
                                                 textlength))) {
                        adapterForListview.add(lv_arr[i]);
                    }
                }
            }

            lv.setAdapter(adapterForListview);
        }
    });

}

public void viewData() {
    // Cursor cursor = conRes.query(CONTENT_URI_Applicant, new String[] {
    // _ID,
    // FName, LName }, null, null, FName);
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(CONTENT_URI_rawquery, null,
            "Select _id,FName,LName FROM Applicant", null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        // Could use getColumnIndexOrThrow() to get indexes
        adapterForListview.add(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(FName))
                + "         "
                + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LName)));
        // i++;
        // Log.i("Id", String.valueOf(item_id[i]));
    }

    item_id = new long[cursor.getCount()];
    lv_arr = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    int i = 0;
    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
        item_id[i] = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));
        lv_arr[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FName)) + " "
                + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LName));
        Log.v("ite_id:" + i, "" + item_id[i]);
        i++;

    }
    cursor.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `SimpleCursorAdapter` like this

```
String[] from = new String[] { "YourDatabseColumnName" };           
int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};          
SimpleCursorAdapter playerAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice , cursor, from, to);
```

while filtering just use something like this

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
{
    playerAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
}
```

[A good tutorial here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) about using sqlite and showing data.

Comment: thanks by the way, but what i'm i trying to say is, the data on the listvew will be sorted real time,, when i type a, all the other data that does not begins with a will be cleared, and so on...

Comment: i found out another way to filter, lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true); but how to get the id of that particular row if you filter? please help me, it always turning to id 1 for the 1st row even if its on 'R' row

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's to late for the answer, but it could help someone else.

I had the same problem. The solution is that you also have to update the items in the list when doing the filtering. For example, when you get three items in the ListView after the list was filtered, your list (here I mean ArrayList or something else, not confusing with a ListView) with your items should also have only three items so the IDs are always synchronized.

I hope it was helpful.